# как нажать на кнопку с помощью Python + selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

как нажать на кнопку с помощью Python + selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
browser.get('your/website/url')
button = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('button.v-btn.theme--light.primary')
button.click()
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44657559/5698975)